# INSERT INTO allows SELECT using non-existent column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When executing the following:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
    A1 INT,
    A2 INT
)

INSERT INTO TableA (A1, A2) VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4);

CREATE TABLE #TempTable1 (ColumnA INT, ColumnB INT);
CREATE TABLE #TempTable2 (ColumnA INT, ColumnB INT);

INSERT INTO #TempTable1 (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES (1, 2);

INSERT INTO #TempTable2
    SELECT A1, A2
    FROM TableA
    WHERE A1 IN (SELECT ColumnA FROM #TempTable1);

SELECT * FROM TableA;
SELECT * FROM #TempTable1;
SELECT * FROM #TempTable2;
```

The results are as follows:

```
TableA
A1  A2
1   2
3   4

#TempTable1
ColumnA ColumnB
1       2

#TempTable2
ColumnA ColumnB
1       2
```

However, if I change the #TempTable2 insert statement so that it selects a non-existent column A1 from #TempTable1:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable2
    SELECT A1, A2
    FROM TableA
    WHERE A1 IN (SELECT A1 FROM #TempTable1);
```

Then #TempTable2 contains all the data from TableA:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
1       2
3       4
```

I am wondering why the execution of the INSERT statement doesn't generate an error as the column A1 does not exist in #TempTable1. For example, if I try to add the following statement:

```
SELECT A1 FROM #TempTable1;
```

I get:

```
Invalid column name 'A1'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called `correlated sub-query`. Referring the outer query column inside `Sub-Query`

The column `A1` is referred from the outer query (ie) `TableA`. So when you execute the query together it is working and when you execute alone it is not working

It will be interpreted as

```
SELECT A1, A2
FROM TableA A
WHERE A1 IN (SELECT A.A1  -- Here check the alias A
             FROM #TempTable1);
```

Normally when using `EXISTS/NOT EXISTS` the query will be correlated in `where` clause.

```
select * from tableA A 
where exists (select 1 from tableB B 
              where A.Id = B.Id  -- A.Id is referred from tableA
              )
```

In your example it is referred in `Select`

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers already answer why you get the results you do, I think there's another aspect to this worth covering: this is a very good example of why you should use table aliases.

If you had aliased the code as follows you would have received the error you were expecting:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable2
    SELECT a.A1, a.A2
    FROM TableA a
    WHERE a.A1 IN (SELECT t.A1 FROM #TempTable1 t);
```

Without aliases, SQL Server (and other DBMS products) will happily default to the one column that matches a name you've given. This leads to mistakes when people do exactly what you've done, but fail to notice the problem. With aliases in place you would simply receive an error, notice the problem, and correct it.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable2
    SELECT A1, A2
    FROM TableA
    WHERE A1 IN (SELECT A1 FROM #TempTable1);
```

In this query `SELECT A1 FROM #TempTable1` is subquery. A1 is not found in `#TempTable1` but you use it as a subquery for each row of `TableA` so A1 is known as a value taken from upper table. Your subquery is equivalent to `WHERE 1 IN (SELECT 1 FROM #TempTable1);` because A1 is constant value for each execution of subquery.